# How many mitzvos derabanan are there?

Tags: mitzvah, statistics

We know that there are 613 Mitzvos min HaTorah, but are there any authoritative opinions who have counted up the total number of Rabbinic Mitzvos (I'd imagine that there are differing opinions and this would be an approximation anyway).

Comment: Are you asking about the seven mitzvos that were added immediately after the 613 in the Torah or in general all the Rabbinic Mitzvos in the gemara and later? If the first, it is a duplicate. If the secon, then it is too broad.